# python script - grouping words into a If-Not statement

Tags: python, web-scraping, terminal, macos-sierra

Trying to figure out how to use an if not statement in which I can group three to four words to omit from a CSV file. Towards the bottom of the code, you'll see that I'm stuck at:  `if ('reddit', 'passwords') not in x:`

Any help would be great.

```
# import libraries
import bs4
from urllib2 import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/NHLStreams/comments/71uhwi/game_thread_sabres_at_maple_leafs_730_pm_et/'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")


filename = "sportstreams.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "Sport Links " + "\n"
f.write(headers)

links = page_soup.select("form a[href]")
for link in links:
    href = link["href"]
    print(href)

    f.write(href + "\n")



with open('sportstreams.csv') as f,open('sstream.csv', "w") as f2:
    for x in f:
        if ('reddit', 'passwords') not in x: # trying to find multi words to omit
            f2.write(x.strip()+'\n')
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want `if (...) not in x` to do. Do all the elements have to be missing from `x`, or is any one of them sufficient to trigger the `if`?

Comment: I guess my code is weak as I'm trying to simplify my results with any line containing the word "reddit" "/r/" and "/password" to be omitted. This will shorten my list of links which would be a success for me. :)

Comment: Please edit an explanation into your question to make it complete. It would be nice if you could show specific examples of lines you want to omit vs ones you want to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the builtin function [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
if all(t not in x for t in ('reddit', 'passwords')):
```

Or [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if not any(t in x for t in ('reddit', 'passwords')):
```

Here's it is in your context manager:

```
with open('sportstreams.csv') as f, open('sstream.csv', "w") as f2:
    for line in f:
        if any(t in line for t in ('reddit', 'passwords')):
            # The line contains one of the strings.
            continue
        else:
            # The line contains none of the strings.
            f2.write(line.strip() + '\n')
```

Comment: This isn't working my friend. What could I be doing wrong? I replaced `if ('reddit', 'passwords') not in x:`  with what you wrote. Doesn't omit lines that contain reddit or password. :(

Comment: @JamesDean that's partially your own fault. The spec in your question is extremely unclear.

Comment: I apologize. What should I do in regards to omitting any line that contains those elements (reddit, /r/, /password)?

Comment: @JamesDean: I've added an example of the context manager to my answer. You want to omit lines containing `'reddit'` or `'password'`, correct? Your post is a bit unclear.

Comment: @ZachGates Thx. I gave it a go, and came back with a result of : `NameError: name 'x' is not defined` - do I change the x to t?

Comment: Adding the continue is unnecessary. Just add a not in front of the any.

Comment: @JamesDean: That's my fault. I forgot to replace `x` with `line`. I've updated the code.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I added the `continue` so that the OP could see what was happening, and also so I could add an inline comment inside the suite.

Comment: `if not any` would accomplish the same purpose more elegantly.